# Save BLOB into MySQL using web2py

Tags: python, mysql, blob, web2py, data-access-layer

Using the web2py framework I want to select a file via a file type input and save it's contents into a MySQL BLOB type field. The file contains binary data.

I need to use DAL for connection management but I have an SQL procedure to do the task. The problem is when I try this below I get error for the SQL syntax.

```
f = form.vars.element.file.read()
db.executesql( "CALL someproc('" + f + "');" )
```

I've tried inserting the raw binary in lots of ways and got the same or similar error. I've also tried to use MySQLdb directly like:

```
f = form.vars.element.file.read()
db.cursor().execute( "CALL someproc('" + f + "');" )
db.commit()
```

This works perfectly but I need to use the above DAL version so the problem is still open.

I've spent 3 days solving this task without luck. :(
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your second example works, given that the `DAL.executesql` method ultimately calls `cursor().execute()` in exactly the same way. In any case, if you want to use the latter syntax in conjunction with the web2py `DAL` object, you can access the cursor via `db._adaptor.cursor`. So, your second example would change to:

```
db = DAL('mysql://...')
db._adapter.cursor.execute( "CALL someproc('" + f + "');" )
```

Another option might be to use the `.callproc` method:

```
db._adapter.cursor.callproc('someproc', (f, ))
```

Note, `db.executesql()` also takes placeholders:

```
db.executesql('...WHERE name=%s', ('Mary', ))
```

but I'm not sure that would work for passing arguments to a stored procedure.

Comment: It seams db._adapter.cursor.callproc(...) did the trick from the 3. Thanks!

Comment: In your question, you indicated `db.cursor().execute( "CALL someproc('" + f + "');" )` worked. In that code, is `db` a `MySQLdb` connection object? If so, I would expect `db._adapter.cursor.execute( "CALL someproc('" + f + "');" )` to work as well, as it ultimately calls `cursor().execute()`.

Comment: To me it seams to be a python string handling problem. I figured it would be the same to use the cursor directly through DAL but somehow it isn't.

Comment: Hmm, as you can see [here](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/gluon/dal/connection.py#L93), `db._adapter.cursor` is the object returned by `connection.cursor()`, so calling `.execute()` on either one should produce the same results. Anyway, I'm glad the alternative works for you.